# Approval for event creation in Sharepoint Calendar

Tags: sharepoint-calendar, microsoft-flow

I tried creating a workflow and made my manager the person who would get the notification and was expecting her to have the power to reject the event creation but I was allowed to create the event, although she was just notified.

Now to support the above statement I should tell you that I am trying to make a system in Sharepoint Calendar so that whenever a person tries to schedule a meeting or event, it should first go to the person of authority and should only appear on the calendar when that person of authority has approved it.

I even tried creating a Microsoft Flow for it, but wasn't able to because the Calendar doesn't show up in the list of 'Lists'.

I just want to know if this is the correct way of achieving that, and if yes what am I doing wrong? If no, then what's the better way?

Answer (score 0):

Even though MS Flow doesn't show the Calendar lists in the options you can still type it in the Calendar List name there when you choose Custom Value.

Also, you could enable "Content Approval" on your Calendar list and have them approved in MS Flow by using a combination of "Approvals" and SharePoint REST API to approved the items

> In SharePoint

[image]

> In MS Flow

[image]

Comment: Pardon me, I don't see how to enable content approval in your screenshot though, I must be missing something?